# Let $L^{'}$ a splitting field of $X^n - 1$ over $L$ s.t $\text {char} (K) = 0$. Why does there exist a primitive $n$-rooth of unity $\xi \in L^{'}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $0$, $L \supset K$ a radical field extension and $L^{'}$ a splitting field of $X^n - 1$ over $L$.

I know $L^{'} \supset K$ is finite and seperable and there exist an extension field $N \supset L^{'}$ such that $N$ is finite and Galois.

Why is it true that there exist a primitive $n$-rooth of unity $\xi \in L^{'}$ ?

I see that $X^{n} -1$ splits over $L^{'}$ into linear factors, but why must $\alpha_i$ of one of these factors $(X - \alpha_i)$ be a primitive $n$-root of unity ?

Answer (score 1):

Assume otherwise, i.e. all $\alpha\in L'$ with $\alpha^n=1$ are in fact lower order roots of unity, i.e. $\alpha^m=1$ for some $m<n$ (with $m$ depending on $\alpha$); then at least we know that $m\mid n$, but it *might* happen that we never have $m=n$.
In other words, if we let $\phi(n)$ denote the number of *primitive* $n$th roots of unity in $\overline L$, it migh a priori happen that $\phi(n)=0$ for some $n$.
But, as the $n$ zeroes of $X^n-1$ are distinct (characteristic $0$!), we see that
$$\tag1 n=\sum_{d\mid n}\phi(d)$$
(not only for the given $n$, but for all $n\in\mathbb N$). Equation $(1)$ also holds if $\phi$ is the Euler function, i.e. the number of coprime (to $n$) numbers in $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. By induction, it follows that $\phi(n)$ indeed *is* the Euler function. Especially, $\phi(n)>0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: How do you see $ X^n - 1$ is irreducible, I guess you use this fact here ?

Comment: Also what does $ \bar L $ denote ?

Answer (score 1):

I think, we can argue as follows. $\mathbb Q$ is the prime field of characteristic 0, so we start working there. In the polynomial Ring $\mathbb Q[X]$, we have $$X^n - 1 = \Pi_{d|n} \Phi_d(X)$$ where $\Phi_d(X)$ is the d-th cyclotomic polynomial. We also know that the cyclotomic polynomials are irreducible over $\mathbb Q$. So, every root of $\Phi_n$ over $\mathbb Q$ must have multiplicative order $n$ (i.e. is a primitive n-th root of unity), otherwise $\Phi_n$ would have a common factor with some $X^m - 1$ for $m < n$, which is not true (see decompostion above). So the field $U := \mathbb Q[X] / ( (\Phi_n(X))$ contains a root of $\Phi_n$ and thus a primitive n-th root of unity, say $\eta$.

Now we come to your fields. The relation $\Phi_n(X) | X^n - 1$ holds in $\mathbb Q[X]$ and thus also in $L'[X]$ since $\mathbb Q$ embeds in $L'$ because of characterisitc 0. So $L'$, as a splitting field of $X^n - 1$, contains a root of $\Phi_n$ (in fact, all $\phi(n)$ roots). Denote this root by $\zeta$. Now, by standard facts from field theory, the embedding $\mathbb Q \rightarrow L'$ gives rise to the substitution homomorphism $\sigma: \mathbb Q[X] \rightarrow L'$ via $X \mapsto \zeta$. The kernel of $\sigma$ is exactly the ideal $(\Phi_n(X)) \subseteq \mathbb Q[X]$ since $\zeta$ is a root of $\Phi_n(X)$ and $\Phi_n(X)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[X]$. So $\sigma$ induces a field homomorphism $\tau: U \rightarrow L'$ (see definition of $U$ above). Now, $U$ contains the primitive n-th root of unity $\eta$, and field homomorphisms are injective, so they don't change multiplicative order. So, $\tau(\eta) \in L'$ is a primitive n-th root of unity.